# Django upload_to by 'username'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to upload a file by username.

```
class Beat(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    author      = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    owner       = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='beats', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', blank=True, null=True)

    mbeat = models.FileField(upload_to='beat/', default = 'static/None/No-beat.mp3')
```

This is my abstract code. This code uploads a file to 'beat' folder.

However, I want to make the storage more effective in visibility. I tried to add an author name to the `upload_to` parameter like this:

```
upload_to='beat/%s/' %author
```

but this didn't make it.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by following

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/beat/author/<filename>
    return 'beat/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.author, filename)

class Beat(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    author      = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    owner       = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='beats', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    default='', blank=True, null=True)
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path,  default = 'static/None/No-beat.mp3')
```

Reference [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

Comment: That is for development only, it does not work on production

Answer (score -2):

You can pass to `upload_to` a function, like this:

```
mbeat = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to_path(path='beat'),
                              default = 'static/None/No-beat.mp3')
```

This function must return a `partial`

```
def upload_to_path(path):
    return partial(_get_upload_to_path, path=path)


def _get_upload_to_path(instance, filename, path):
    """

    :param instance: instance of the model
    :param filename: filename of the uploaded file
    :param path: path to the directory where to upload
    :return: complete path with filename
    """
    return os.path.join(path, instance.author, filename)
```

With `partial` you can "freeze" the invocation of a function, passing always the parameters indicated in the partial call, in this case the path specified in the odel. At runtime, the function will receive the argument passed from django (which expect a function that accept instance and filename for the upload_to attribute) and the one you specified in the partial. From that you can return the complete path